# How can I get Phoenix to join channels automatically when a client connects?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I'm using websocket transport with Phoenix Channels, but I'm trying to provide a clean API for consumers without a `Phoenix.Socket` client to use with just websockets.

For simplicity, I'd like to auto-subscribe users to various channels when they open a session.

Currently I have something like:

```
defmodule MyWeb.UserSocket do
  require Logger
  use Phoenix.Socket
  alias Exchange.{Account, ApiKey}

  channel "room:time", MyWeb.TimeChannel
  channel "alpha:*", MyWeb.AlphaChannel
  channel "beta:*", MyWeb.BetaChannel

  def connect(%{"api-key" => _} = params, socket, connect_info) do
    with %{"api-key" => api_key, "api-expires" => api_expires, "api-signature" => api_signature} <-
           params,
         {:ok, %ApiKey{} = key} <- ApiKey.fetch(api_key),
         {:ok, %Account{} = account} <-ApiKey.authorize(...)) do
      Logger.info("Authorized account #{account.account_id} via API key on websocket")

      #JOIN CHANNELS HERE

      {:ok, assign(socket, :account, account)}
    else
      {:error, e} ->
        Logger.error("Websocket auth error #{inspect(e)}")
        {:ok, socket}
    end
  end

end
```

What do I need to put in "**Join Channels Here**" to get it to subscribe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was not to use Phoenix Channels on the interface, but write a separate `Transport` implementation that subscribed to Phoenix.

I created a new Socket Transport by defining a new module:

```
@behaviour Phoenix.Socket.Transport
```

And provided a socked in `endpoint.ex`:

```
socket "/realtime", MyWeb.MyCustomSocket, websocket: true
```

This pattern follows a `GenServer` type layout. I subscribed to the Phoenix Channels I wanted in `init` and then re-emitted these events to the socket.

This created a one-way websocket that doesn't require any knowledge of `Socket` to connect and listen to.

Answer (score 1):

this might be too simple but have you tried

```
Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe(MyApp.PubSub, "topic")
```

?

Documentation - https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_pubsub/Phoenix.PubSub.html

Comment: Thanks! This appears to subscribe the current process to receive messages from a channel, but I think we're looking for something that takes and returns a socket I.e. %Socket{} = subscribe(socket, room)